# PHP heredoc does not take linefeed

Tags: php, apache, heredoc

I got a mystery when I tried to test a heredoc construct in PHP.
I can not figure out what is a problem with this code:

```
<?php
$author = "Scott Adams";
$out = <<<_END
Normal people believe that if it ain't broke, don't fix it.      
Engineers believe that if it ain't broke, it doesn't have enough
features yet.
- $author.
_END;

echo  $out;
?>
```

According to my book here is not necessary to use the \n to put a linefeed, just type an enter button. But it does not take linefeed just print the text and that is it. Do I have problem with my apache server or May it be misconfigured? I am using it with the default settings.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are you looking at, the output in a browser or the source code?

Comment: I am looking at the browser. I run the source code in Netbeans and the output appears in the Mozilla, but I checked this out with Chromium brower too and I got the some problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browsers all white-space (tabs, new-lines, multiple spaces) is collapsed.

If you want to show new-lines in the browser, you need to add html line-breaks:

```
echo nl2br($out);
```